# Why can't sub-packages see package private classes?

Tags: java, inheritance, package, organization

Okay so, I have this project structure:

package A.B

- class `SuperClass` (this class is marked package private)

package A.B.C

- class `SubClass` (inherits from super class)

I'd rather not make `SuperClass` publicly visible... It is really just a utility class for this specific project (A.B).

It seems to me that SubClass should be able to see `SuperClass`, because package A.B.C is a subpackage of A.B... but this is not the case.

What would be the best way to resolve this issue?  I don't think it makes sense to move everything in A.B.C up to A.B or move A.B down to A.B.C... mainly because there will probably be an A.B.D which inherits from stuff in A.B as well...

I'm a bit new to Java, so be nice :D  (I'm a C++ and .NET guy)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Packages are unique identifiers. You cannot make them follow the inheritance rules. Package and SubPackages are not analogical to Super and Sub classes.

I dont see any flaws in making the class that you wanted to use in the sub package to be visible to the outside world. I would be interested to know how this criterion is handled in C++/.net (as I am a java guy :) )

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured I was just misunderstanding packages

Comment: In .NET I would've just put the classes in folders and have them marked internal :)

Comment: I don't get the inheritance-related analogy. Packages are namespaces. Namespaces are hierarchical by definition. That Java's package private classes are not visible in sub-packages is simply wrong.

Comment: @AlexandruNedelcu - "Namespaces are hierarchical by definition" - Not according to java.

Comment: I don't quite get this logic either tbh. Making package private visible to sub packages just makes sense, unless I'm missing a clear argument.

Comment: I'm here 2 years later with the same question. Lmao.

Answer (score 9):

Your best bet is to declare the (default) constructor(s) of `SuperClass` as `protected`. This way only classes in the same package and subclasses regardless of the package can instantiate it and extend from it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put them in the same package level?

Could you somehow use composition instead of inheritance? I've been trying to do more of this myself after reading Effective Java. Not sure if this is possible given your needs, but it might be worth considering.

Good luck.

Comment: I don't want them in the same package level because I'll have around 20-30 classes that will rely on the super class, and I'm trying to keep things organized lol.