# How to hide a java package from anything at least two levels removed in the hierarchy

Tags: java, android

I have a package structure that looks like this:

```
a
a.b
a.b.c
```

where `a` has hundreds of subpackages besides `b`, `b` has a few subpackages besides `c`, and `c` contains many classes. What I want is for `a.b` to be able to access the classes in `a.b.c` but for classes outside `a.b` to not be able to access them. (I don't care whether `a.b.x` can access them.) I know that if I moved the classes in `a.b.c` into `a.b` then I could make them package-private and prevent them from being accessed elsewhere, but this would significantly clutter the source, reducing understandability, and therefore I do not think it's worth the tradeoff. Is there another more nuanced way to accomplish this?

Note: I've looked at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489096/why-cant-sub-packages-see-package-private-classes) and while it is similar, they are asking about the opposite direction.

Comment: Look into java modules: https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html

Comment: @nylanderdev this is really cool, thank you for pointing me to this! Unfortunately Android currently only supports up to Java 8. I realize now that I tagged it as Android but failed to mention Android in the description or title.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a new idea -- I could add a custom lint rule checking that `a.b.c.*` classes are not accessed outside `a.b`. It's still not as good as those classes not being accessible in the first place, but at least could point out the issue so it can get corrected more quickly.