# One class using all other classes package organization

Tags: java, oop, package

I'm writing a Java project where I have a main class and many other classes. The main class uses all the other classes and the other classes can be divided to logical groups.

The structure is something like this:

- CoffeePlace
- AbstractWorker
- BaristaWorker
- DishWasherWorker
- CashierWorker
- AbstractMachine
- CoffeeMachine
- OrangeJuiceMachine
- IceCreamMachine

Naturally I would divide them as:

- coffeeplace (package)

  - CoffeePlace
  - worker (package)

    - AbstractWorker
    - BaristaWorker
    - DishWasherWorker
    - CashierWorker
  - machine (package)

    - AbstractMachine
    - CoffeeMachine
    - OrangeJuiceMachine
    - IceCreamMachine

There is a problem with this design, the CoffeePlace class needs to know all the other classes located in the sub packages, and the only way they can be seen by CoffeePlace is to make all their interface methods public, but now IceCreamMachine can call BaristraWorker methods which seem to not make sense and break the encapsulation.

Is it possible to organize these classes in packages making the machines and workers only visible to the main class and not to each other?

Comment: Probably with a Worker and Machine interface and some factory in each package, that can be static methods in the interfaces.

Comment: Have  you investigated the [JPMS](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3543253/what-is-jpms-introducing-the-java-platform-module-system.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to to solve this is to use the [factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):  a factory class in the `machine` package would create instances of `AbstractMachine`. Another factory in the `worker` package would create instances of the `AbstractWorker`:

- The factory and the abstract classes would be public. Only the factory classes would know the different specialisations of the abstract class.
- The `CoffePlace` would only need to know the abstract classes and the factories.
- The remaining classes can be kept non-public at package level, i.e. [not visible across the different branches and sub-bbranches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2489096/3723423) of your hierarchical presentation.

If the `CoffeePlace` needs to know more about an `OrangeJuiceMachine` than the interface provided by `AbstractMachine`, then, you are not really abstracting the machines; The design could benefit from some improvements, such as for example considering the use of the [Entity System Component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) pattern to favour [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Of course, `public` is `public`. So the factories and the abstract classes could still be hijacked.  But what leaks is significantly reduced.